# Converting regexp pattern to lowercase

Tags: python, regex, xml

I have some XML text like this:

```
text = '<sp> <speaker>T<seg rend="small">ARSIS</seg>. </speaker> <p>—Adelante, Señora. Gracias á la luz rosada, franquearemos sin tropezones este ingrato sendero.</p> </sp> <sp> <speaker>L<seg rend="small">A</seg> M<seg rend="small">ADRE</seg>. </speaker> <p>—La llovizna nos coge ahora de cara… Yo no la temo. Tengo mi rostro bien curtido para estas inclemencias que hacen á mis hijos duros, y tan insensibles al frío como al calor. Tú también te has endurecido, según veo, y te has dejado en los aires sutiles y en los ardores del sol tu antigua carita de galancete afeminado.</p>'
```

I want everything in the `<seg rend="small">` to become lowercase, like:

```
 <sp> <speaker>T<seg rend="small">arsis</seg>. </speaker> <p>—Adelante, Señora. Gracias á la luz rosada, franquearemos sin tropezones este ingrato sendero.</p> </sp> <sp> <speaker>L<seg rend="small">a</seg> M<seg rend="small">adre</seg>. </speaker> <p>—La llovizna nos coge ahora de cara… Yo no la temo. Tengo mi rostro bien curtido para estas inclemencias que hacen á mis hijos duros, y tan insensibles al frío como al calor. Tú también te has endurecido, según veo, y te has dejado en los aires sutiles y en los ardores del sol tu antigua carita de galancete afeminado.</p> </sp> <sp> <speaker>T<seg rend="small">arsis</seg>. </speaker> <p>—En los días ásperos de la Aldehuela empecé á soltar mi máscara de cera, y cambié los goznes quebradizos de mi máquina corporal por otros de acero.</p> </sp> <sp> <speaker>L<seg rend="small">a</seg> M<seg rend="small">adre</seg>. </speaker> <p>—Al nombrar la Aldehuela traes á mi memoria algo que tenía que decirte, y es cosa en verdad lamentable. ¿Sabes que ha muerto el pobre José Caminero?</p> </sp>
```

I have tried different variants of something like this in Python:

```
    for f in re.findall(r'<seg rend="small">([^<]*?)</seg>', text):
        text = text.replace(f, f.lower())
```

But it doesn't work and I get weird results like `<seg rend="small">aDRE</seg>`, no idea why. Could please anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Do Not Parse XML with Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1547004)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use regex..

```
>>> txt = 'foo <seg rend="small">ARSIS</seg> bar'
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'(<seg\s+rend\s*=\s*"small">)(.*?)(?=</seg>)', lambda m: m.group(1) + m.group(2).lower(), txt)
'foo <seg rend="small">arsis</seg> bar'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, do not parse HTML with regex. That being said, you could use **`lxml`**:

```
from lxml import html

text = '<sp> <speaker>T<seg rend="small">ARSIS</seg>. </speaker> <p>—Adelante, Señora. Gracias á la luz rosada, franquearemos sin tropezones este ingrato sendero.</p> </sp> <sp> <speaker>L<seg rend="small">A</seg> M<seg rend="small">ADRE</seg>. </speaker> <p>—La llovizna nos coge ahora de cara… Yo no la temo. Tengo mi rostro bien curtido para estas inclemencias que hacen á mis hijos duros, y tan insensibles al frío como al calor. Tú también te has endurecido, según veo, y te has dejado en los aires sutiles y en los ardores del sol tu antigua carita de galancete afeminado.</p>'

tree = html.fromstring(text)
results = [x.lower() for x in tree.xpath('//seg[@rend="small"]/text()')]
print results
```

**Output:**

```
['arsis', 'a', 'adre']
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for your answer, but the thing is that I deal with very crappy HTML, not even wellformed, so I can't work directly with lxml. Maybe I should have said that in first place. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, tagging the question "xml" when the data isn't XML is probably not a good idea.